# creating map with vector/list iterator as key

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, vector, iterator

I am confused over the cause of this humongous error in `g++` in this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> p={1,2,3,4};

    map<list<int>::iterator, int> q;

    q[p.begin()]=9991;

    cout<<q[p.begin()]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There is error when `list` is used but not when `vector` is used - why? I understand how a `list`**\**`vector` behaves (theoretically) but still I can't find a reason for this.

**ERROR:**

> error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const std::_List_iterator’ and ‘const std::_List_iterator’)
>          { return __x < __y; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard class `std:: list` has bidirectional iterators that do not  have the `operator <` while `std::vector` has direct access iterators for which the `operator <` is defined.

This `operator <` is used for ordering data in `std::map` because by default it uses the function object `std::less`.

Here is a declaration of the class template std::map

```
template<class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T>>>
class map;
```

Comment: So basically iterators are holding the address hence they can't be compared as the memory in `list` is not continuous?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus In general the operator < is not defined for bidirectional iterators and as you correctly mentioned addresses of list nodes can not be compared.

Comment: can you please provide me some link to read more about this ordering requirement and what mechanics is used to create the order?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Iterators in a `list` are only aware of their current, previous and next elements. So if two iterators refer to elements that are more than 1 element apart, they can't tell which comes first. The address of elements can't be used for this. There's no way to know if a higher address means an element that comes earlier or later in the sequence. `list` elements can be all over the place in memory. So since comparison can only theoretically work for a limited set of iterator pairs, it's not possible to implement a general case comparison operator for them.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus See my updated post which I appended with the class template declaration of std::map.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux IMHO I think despite being aware about the next and the previous element the current element can't determine whose address is having a higher value (the next one or the previous one) reason being the discontinuous nature of `list` due to which this comparison fails. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus The address does not matter. Elements in a `list` can go back and forth in memory. There is no requirement that the order in memory matches the order in the container.